Top bar not showing in SharePoint Subscription Edition
We have provisioned an instance of SharePoint Subscription Edition in our environment. We're noticing that the Tiles (arrow #1) and user information is not showing up in the top-left and top-right of the screen:

We're also noticing that when we go to "Site Contents", the New dropdown that lets us create a new subsite or document library is also missing.

I've seen online people pointing to things like UPS, but that's been configured in our environment. And, as far as I can tell, it is working without issues. Note sure how to troubleshoot this...
Dec 16th update:
I've tried configuring a new web application and site collection, but still getting the same problem. I'm noticing, however, that the tiles navigation shows up when I go to the MySites:

Anyone with any ideas, please!!
Additional Information:
I'm noticing that when I go to:
https://sitecollection.domain.local/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/GetMyProperties
I am getting the following error:
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code>-1, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileException</m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">An error was encountered while retrieving the user profile.</m:message>
</m:error>

I'm now wondering whether this is related to UPS.

Have you configured AAM in the web application?

Yes both web applications have AAM configured. They are in the "Default" zone.

I had this same problem not long ago in MS Edge. Here's what I ended up trying and I got my new button back. I reset Edge and cleared cache.
Close Edge
Open Task Manager and End any Edge Task

Go to C:\Users\MyLogin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge

Right-click on the "User Data" folder and click on rename

Enter a new name for the folder like "User DataOld" or "User
Data0" and press enter to save the change

Relaunch the Microsoft Edge and check if the problem was fixed


I cleared cache all time also. I hope this works for you.

This did not work, unfortunately. I don't believe this is a caching problem.

Sorry to hear that. Hope somebody has an idea.

Is it possible that the settings have been changed in SharePoint Administration here?  I have traced such problems back to these settings in prior lives:


My question relates to SharePoint on-premise, not SharePoint Online.
